# Removing Wrap Function from JSONP Response Using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, jsonp

I'm making an AJAX call to an API and getting a JSONP response as one big string that is all wrapped in the callback function used to make the call. I want to parse the response to an actual javascript object using the JSON.parse() method but the wrap function is preventing the parse() method from working. The JSONP response looks like this:

```
1: jsonpFunction(
2: {
3:    "response": {
4:       "version":"0.1",

...     ...

962:    }
963: );
```

I want to remove all of lines 1 and 963 so that I can parse the rest. I've managed to do it using regular expressions, but I had to use the replace() method twice:

```
var fixedResponse = response.replace(/jsonpFunction\(/g,'').replace(/\);/g,'');
```

I'm a beginning web development student so I'm new to regular expressions. How can I combine the regular expressions so that I only have to use the replace() method once?

Comment: How are you receiving the data? The whole point of JSONP is to include a `<script>` element that makes the request and then (automatically) calls the function that is in the prefix, passing the data to it. I.e. if you refer to the API via a `<script>` tag, define the function `jsonpFunction` first and it will be passed the data. If you calling the API via AJAX, you should configure the request so it doesn't return you JSONP in the first place.

Comment: @felixkling You're right, the problem is that at this point I need the response to be in JSONP because I need to avoid violating the same origin policy. If I try to make an ordinary JSON or XML request to an API, I get a 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'http://wherever.com/' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error. Honestly, I don't yet understand the concepts behind what is happening with this error. I haven't learned anything about back-end code or working with servers yet. I'm just trying to figure out the regular expressions.

Comment: That means that if you are using JSONP, then you are not using Ajax (and that's OK). But where is `response` coming from then? Please provide a complete example. See [mcve] for guidance. Also have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP to get a better understanding of what JSONP is and how it works. *"I'm just trying to figure out the regular expressions."* The point is that if you are doing JSONP "correctly", there is no need to use a regular expression.

Comment: Did you ever get this working!?